# SQL select Query

Tags: sql

Pleaes help me to select (**Tot-Goals, Tot-Goals-against, Goal-Diff for Each Team**) I am using  Table called [Match Details] and Fields are

```
*Tour-Id, Match Id, Team-Id, Goals*
    1       1          1       1
    1       1          2       1
    1       1          1       1
    1       2          1       1
    1       2          3       1
```

I am using query

**PARAMETERS TourLong;

```
SELECT Team-Id, SUM(Goals) as goals
FROM [Match Details]
WHERE [tourid] = Tour
GROUP BY club, tourid;
```

i am getting team's Goals but not against goal

Comment: Your table structure is in not correct format.You stored only team id,Where is your against team id in that table.

Comment: what do you mean by goal difference? Please explain the columns

Comment: Thx Siva... Goal Different is (Tot-Goal    -   Tot-Goals-against)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is a query language not a DBMS product)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wnated?

```
create table #MatchDetails ( tour_id int,macth_id int ,team_id int,goal int)

insert into #MatchDetails values(1,1,1,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,1,2,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,2,3,6);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,2,2,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,3,1,4);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,3,3,1);

    select  m1.team_id as team_id,SUM(m1.goal) as totalgoal,SUM(m2.goal) as totalgoalagainst,SUM(m1.goal)-SUM(m2.goal) as totaldifference   from #MatchDetails m1    inner join #MatchDetails m2 
      on m1.macth_id=m2.macth_id and m1.team_id!=m2.team_id
    Where m1.tour_id=1
    group by  m1.team_id
drop table #MatchDetails;
```

output

```
 team_id    totalgoal   totalgoalagainst    totaldifference
    1         5          2                   3
    2         2          7                  -5
    3         7          5                   2
```

Let me know if i could be more help.

Comment: Thanks Amair,  i t ried ur query but not working.. totalgoal and totalgoalagainst showing same result

Comment: tot-Goals-againsist the goal that opponent had scored against team right?

Comment: Yes Amir..but ur query result totalgoal &  totalgoalagainst same value             team_id2 totalgoal totalgoalagainst totaldifference
1 5 5 0
2 2 2 0
3 7 7 0

Comment: Can you provide me the expected result with the valid table data on your question. I see on your question there are three match id with 1. I assume that there should be only two same match id as on one match id there could be only two teams playing. Am i right?

Comment: i created same table as u given                                                                tour_id    macth_id   team_id       goal
1               1             1                  1
1                 1                  2                   1
1                 2                  3              6
1                 2             2                  1
1                 3             1                  4
1                 3              3            1

Comment: for one match 2 Team Id and  i am adding all action of football game .not only goal

Comment: You mean you didn't get the result as the output i have stated on my answer running the same query?

Comment: i dont understand how same query gave you different result. That query will give the exact output as i gave on my answer if you are running same query. And is my output on my answer is expected result by you?

Comment: Hi Amir, its working now.. iam using Access here, instead of m1.team_id!=m2.team_id change to m1.team_id<>m2.team_id           Thank you Amir

Comment: Hi Amir, its showing wrong result when i insert data  following                                                                                            insert     into           #MatchDetails values(1,1,1,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,1,2,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,2,1,1);
insert into #MatchDetails values(1,2,1,1);

Comment: You are inserting same row twice (1,2,1,1) that might be the problem. If it worked please accept my answer